# Right Syntax of SQL Query (SQL 2008)

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2008:

```
ACCOUNT(username,password,task);
COMMENT(idcom,content,username,time,idtopic);
TOPIC(idtopic,title);
```

I've had a query to get NUM (row number), idcom, content, iptopic, username,task,time:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) as NUM, idcom, content, idtopic, b.username, b.task, time 
 from COMMENT a 
 LEFT JOIN ( select username, task from ACCOUNT) b 
 ON a.username=b.username 
 where idtopic='1' ---> I call it: Temp Table
```

Then I want to get all rows from Temp Table from row 6 (7,8,9,...). 
I've tried many times but it seems I dont know the right syntax? Help?

Comment: could you try to describe the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) as NUM, idcom, content, idtopic, b.username, b.task, time 
 from COMMENT a 
 LEFT JOIN ( select username, task from ACCOUNT) b 
 ON a.username=b.username 
 where idtopic='1' )x where x.Num > 6